# difference drop/come by

Tags: difference, phrase-usage, idiomatic-language

> There's this pizza place right next the supermarket. Me and a few friends hang out there every Friday after school. You should drop/come by sometime.

- What is the difference between these in this context? Are they equally natural here?
- Is there an even more natural choice than my suggestions?

Comment: If you want something colloquial, you can also use *pop in*.

Comment: Come by is mainly N. American; drop by or drop in are both common in UK usage. Both are informal.

Comment: My suggestion is the part you did not query directly. "I hang out there with some friends every Friday after school." Also in BrE we say "next ***to*** the supermarket", not "next the supermarket".

Comment: Some regional British dialects omit the 'to' in 'next to'. My father from Derbyshire said it.